# Angular 6: How to display a component in its parent's outlet?

Tags: angular, typescript, router-outlet

Is there any way to display a component in its parent's router-outlet? These are my routes:

```
{
path: 'myHotels', component: MyHotelsParentComponent,
resolve: {myHotels: MyHotelsResolver},
children: [
  {path: '', component: MyHotelsComponent},
  {
    path: ':hotelId', component: MyHotelComponent,
    resolve: {myHotel: MyHotelResolver, categories: CategoriesResolver},
    children: [
      {path: '', component: MyRoomsComponent},
      {path: 'rooms/:roomId', component: MyRoomComponent, resolve: {myRoom: MyRoomResolver}},
    ]
  },
]},
```

I want to display MyRoomComponent at the same router-outlet as MyHotelsComponent and MyHotelComponent. I also want to keep my resolved data coming from parent routes.

Answer (score 0):

you can have

```
   {path:'',
    children:[
      {path:'rooms/room'...},
      {path:':hotelId'...}
    ]
   }
```

See that you must put "rooms/room" before ":hotelId", the first router Angular find the first component serve

Comment: Thank you for your answer Eliseo. But in your case I lost 'myHotel' resolved data derived from parent route. I want to keep and pass all resolved data to sub-routes

Comment: I want to say that you can have a path='' and several childrens but be carefull if you has a path thats was an parameter because this path must put the last one